# Dataflow - Approx Unique on unbounded source

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm getting unexpected results streaming in the cloud.

My pipeline looks like:

```java
SlidingWindow(60min).every(1min)
        .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(
            AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime
                                .pastFirstElementInPane()   
                                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
                                    )
                            )
    .withAllowedLateness(15sec)
    .accumulatingFiredPanes()
.apply("Get UniqueCounts", ApproximateUnique.perKey(.05))
.apply("Window hack filter", ParDo(
      if(window.maxTimestamp.isBeforeNow())
          c.output(element)
    )
)
.toJSON()
.toPubSub()
```

If that filter isn't there, I get 60 windows per output.  Apparently because the pubsub sink isn't window aware.

So in the examples below, if each time period is a minute, I'd expect to see the unique count grow until 60 minutes when the sliding window closes.

Using DirectRunner, I get expected results:

```
t1: 5
t2: 10
t3: 15
...
tx: growing unique count
```

In dataflow, I get weird results:

```
t1: 5
t2: 10
t3: 0
t4: 0
t5: 2
t6: 0
...
tx: wrong unique count
```

However, if my unbounded source has older data, I'll get normal looking results until it catches up at which point I'll get the wrong results.

I was thinking it had to do with my window filter, but removing that didn't change the results.

If I do a Distinct() then Count().perKey(), it works, but that slows my pipeline considerably.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: What are the keys and the windows associated with each "t" in your log examples? It's helpful to remember that there is no "current window" in Beam - a record may fall into multiple windows (in your example, every point maps into 60 different windows), and aggregations are computed over all windows at the same time (i.e. every point contributes to 60 different aggregations, and you're getting the results of all of them)

Comment: I'm reading a KV<String,String> into the sliding 60 minute windows.  The use case is a chat app and I'm trying to calculate the unique number of people talking per channel.  So it's KV<channelName, userId>.

Comment: re: windows.  I think I understand the point you're trying to make.  However, if I tested for 20 minutes, I'd still expect the unique count to increase in the first 60 windows.  I don't think I'm seeing that.  Can you suggest a better way to output a real time unique count like this?

Comment: Windows of different keys are independent. When you print messages of the form "t : N", can you also print what key it is about, and print what window it is about? (add a BoundedWindow parameter to your ProcessElement method)

Comment: (I would not rule out a bug in ApproximateUnique: we've seen bugs in similar transforms before, combined with complex triggering - so I'd like to get to the bottom of this and would appreciate your help with a reproducing test case)

Comment: I tried this example as part of some other testing. I do see wrong unique counts like you do. The code is here : https://gist.github.com/rangadi/2615ddabd45344104e0188e1d35b3223#file-approximateunique-test-L104
You can ignore reading from Kafka and writting to Kafka part (Pubsub should behave the same). It looks like Dataflow is discarding fired panes. Stay tuned for updates.

Comment: You beat me to it.  Thanks Raghu and jkff.

Comment: I'd like to repeate the question from jkff. In Dataflow many windows can be processed at the same time, which might lead to results that look confusing but are really for different windows.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QS0z2hG1A_4teH5NrDdbQwqE-DSYcRblF80IkxW4xHg/edit?usp=sharing     Here's a comparison using 2 subscriptions to the same topic, looking at one key.  While my filter may be a little hacky, there's a clear difference in behavior that would exist with or without the filter.

Comment: Also, I'm working on writing a failing test, but 1) I need to get my project into production and 2) I can't figure out how to test against the Dataflow runner...or how to use the TestDataflowRunner.

Comment: Sent a fix here : https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4688
Its a bug in extractOutput() in ApproximateUnique. It resets the accumulated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update from the comments]
ApproximateUnique inadvertently resets its accumulated value when result is extracted. This is incorrect when the value is read more than once as with windows firing multiple times. Fix (will be in version 2.4): https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4688